# Como rellenar array desde un datatable

Tags: c#, mysql

estoy haciendo una insercion de datos de una base de datos sql a una datatable para luego volcar esos datos en un arraylist que contendra y sacara las filas, al ejecutar visual recoge las columnas y entra en interrupcion y no consigo averiguar porque

```
string query = "select idpedido,provincia,cliente,datediff(fecha_penalizacion,sysdate()) as 'dias restantes',fecha_inicio,fecha_penalizacion from pedido";




            MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
            MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter2 = new MySqlDataAdapter(query2, connection);

            button1.Enabled = true;

            connection.Open();

            dataAdapter.Fill(TablaPedidos);
            //Crear objetos "Ordenes"
            foreach (DataRow row in TablaPedidos.Rows)
            {

                MyArray.Add(new Ordenes(row["idpedido"].ToString(), row["cliente"].ToString(), row["provincia"].ToString(), row["dias restantes"].ToString()

                , row["fecha_inicio"].ToString(), row["fecha_penalizacion"].ToString()));

            }

            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (SystemException) { MessageBox.Show("i got deaded bro"); };

            MessageBox.Show("Se han recogido " + MyArray.Count() + " columnas");





for(int i = 0;i < MyArray.Count();i++) {
                string mensajeContenidoSimple="<tr bgcolor=" + colorJard + "><td>" + MyArray[i].provincia + "</td><td>" + MyArray[i].Numorden + "</td><td>" + MyArray[i].Nomcliente.ToString().Substring(0, 10) + "..." + "</td><td>" + MyArray[i].Restan + "</td><td>" + "</td></tr>";
                mensajeContenidoSimple += mensajefull;
            }
```

Comment: tienes un  "catch (SystemException)" porque no recoges el mensaje que te devuelve la expcepcion? …...  catch (SystemException ex) {MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

Comment: No está muy claro lo que preguntas. Te llega a sacar el mensaje de "Se han recogido x columnas"?

Comment: Si me saca las columans que ha cogido, ahi me dice ahora que en el bucle y se para en mensajeContenidoSimple, la escepcion es indice y longitud tienen que hacer referencia a un punto de la cadena. nombre del paramentro lenght

Comment: @luiso El error te puede venir del bucle `for` o del `Substring` que haces a `MyArray[i].Nomcliente`, comprueba que ese dato siempre tiene 10 carácteres, sinó petará

Comment: @luiso edita tu pregunta y añade la excepción, ya que es básica para resolver el problema.

Answer (score 2):

La excepción según indicas en los comentarios es la siguiente:

> El índice y la longitud deben hacer referencia a una ubicación en la cadena.
>   Nombre del parámetro: length

Este error es muy claro. Estás intentado obtener una subcadena indicando un mayor tamaño del disponible.

En tu caso, esta es la sentencia problemática:

```
MyArray[i].Nomcliente.ToString().Substring(0, 10)
```

Si `Nomcliente` es de un tamaño menor a 10 caracteres, te lanzará esa excepción.

Lo que puedes hacer es usar el operador ternario [?:](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) para comprobar el tamaño antes de hacer el `SubString`:

```
MyArray[i].Nomcliente.ToString() < 10 ? 
              MyArray[i].Nomcliente.ToString() 
             :MyArray[i].Nomcliente.ToString().Substring(0, 10);
```